# Changing the font color of a timer in javascript

Tags: javascript

I just want to change the font color of my timer to white so it could go well with my preferred background color.

Here's my fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/fpouew9d/.

```js
var CCOUNT = 30;

var t, count;

function cddisplay() {
  // displays time in span
  document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML = count;
};

function countdown() {
  // starts countdown
  cddisplay();
  if (count == 0) {
    // time is up
  } else {
    count--;
    t = setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
  }
};

function cdpause() {
  // pauses countdown
  clearTimeout(t);
};

function cdreset() {
  // resets countdown
  cdpause();
  count = CCOUNT;
  cddisplay();
};
cdreset()
```

```css
p {
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: #242424;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Some text
</p>

<span id="timespan"></span>
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="countdown()">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="cdpause()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="cdreset()">
```

Comment: So you want to change the number shown in the timer? You can use CSS: no need for JS. Just use `#timespan { color: white; }`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Don't use body onload, but instead use `window.addEventListener("load",cdreset)`

Comment: Also, pass *functions* to `setTimeout`, don't use the `eval`-ish string passing...

Comment: The HTML code in [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpouew9d/) is a bit of a mess. You have an opening `<body>` tag without a closing one; a `<p>` tag outside (above) the `body` and a `<style>` tag that is neither in the `head` (which you do not have) nor in the `body`. You might want to fix it; then you can simply add a CSS rule to change `#timespan` color (`#timespan { color: white }`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have `setInterval` function. You can use it instead of hacks around `setTimeout`.

To change color of any text in css:

```
#timespan {
  color: white;
}
```